# Visual studio 2015 visual error when debug

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

sometimes when i debug on visual studio (2015) and I stop for a while in some point, if this point has an error/warning, the "yellow" line appears, but it never dissapears, show you a picture:
[image]

as you see there is not in front of the visual studio is in front of any window, its only disappears when I minimize (appears again when maximize) or when I close VS.

any idea how to fix?

Comment: Try starting visual studio in safemode. The issue maybe is caused by some add-in. Just run `devenv.exe /safemode`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Hadi the problem here is this problem is not happening always, i tried to replicate now even with this ``/safemode` and normally and it didn't jump. thanks anyway

Comment: have u tried to repair visual studio using the installer